# Add a parent layout dynamically and a child linearlayout dynamically

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I currently have my code that is set up to show one TextView in the parent layout and 3 textviews in the same layout by row. My problem is that the 3 textviews are displaying as 3 different rows when I would like to be set up in the same row as a group. I am thinking I need a child linerlayout but this has not worked for me. The 3 textviews are dynamic and I can't set a certain amount of textviews as the data coming in is dynamic. Here is an example of my code of how my code will display....

[Screenshot of 3 textviews in different rows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/45Ht0.png)

My code is the following:

```
//initialize linearlayout
public LinearLayout pickcontainerLayout;


int counter = 0;
//creating a new view by using functions, using keys and values from multimap
        for (String key : myMultimap.keySet()) {
            ArrayList<SaleOrder> sale = new ArrayList<>();
            for (SaleOrder s : myMultimap.get(key)) {
                sale.add(s);
            }
            pickcontainerLayout.addView(containerLayoutfunction(counter, sale.size(), sale, key));
            View line = new View(getContext());
            line.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,1));
            line.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(255,255,255));
            pickcontainerLayout.addView(line);
            counter++;
        } 
private TextView newSku(int id, String sku) {
    TextView skuView = new TextView(getContext());
    skuView.setId(id);
    skuView.setText("SKU: " + sku);
    /*LinearLayout.LayoutParams skuParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
    );
    skuView.setLayoutParams(skuParams);*/
    skuView.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT);
    return skuView;
}
private TextView newqty(int id, String qty) {
    TextView qtyView = new TextView(getContext());
    qtyView.setId(id);
    qtyView.setText("QTY: " + qty);
    /*LinearLayout.LayoutParams qtyParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
    );
    qtyView.setLayoutParams(qtyParams);*/
    qtyView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
    return qtyView;
}
private TextView newlocation(int id, String location) {
    TextView loc = new TextView(getContext());
    loc.setId(id);
    loc.setText("Location: " + location);
    /*LinearLayout.LayoutParams locParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
    );
    loc.setLayoutParams(locParams);*/
    loc.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);
    return loc;
}
private LinearLayout containerLayoutfunction(int parentid, int rowId, ArrayList<SaleOrder> s, String key) {
    LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(getContext());

    layout.addView(newSale(parentid, key));
    layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    for (int i = 0; i<rowId;i++) {
        //LinearLayout layoutchild = new LinearLayout(getContext());
        //layoutchild.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        //layoutchild.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
        layout.addView(newSku(rowId,s.get(i).getSku()));
        layout.addView(newqty(rowId,s.get(i).getQty()));
        layout.addView(newlocation(rowId,s.get(i).getlocation()));
    }
    return layout;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you should wrap the three TextViews in a LinearLayout with horizontal orientation, so the textviews will automatically be on the same row. The container will have FILL_PARENT horizontally as LayuoutParam, while the textview should have WRAP_CONTENT with gravity assigned to LEFT (for the first), CENTER (for the second) and RIGHT (for the third).

Comment: Setting it with a horizontal orientation will have all 4 of my text views on the same line and I do not want that so it kinda has to stay in vertical. Unless there is another way of going about it?

Comment: you can leave the first textview outside the inner linear layout